# ipa and apk size issue

Tags: xamarin.forms, apk, ipa

I am working on Xamarin.Forms project everything going smooth earlier but now I am facing very strange issue while creating ipa and apk file. 
Till One Day before while i was creating apk and ipa the size was near about 25-30MB 
but suddenly it's increases to more than 700MB. 
Now while i am creating ipa and apk file its size showing more than 700MB.

I tried by checking and unchecking Linker Behaviour to 
1-Don't Link
2- Link SDK assembly only
3-Link All SDK.
but not find suitable.

Please Help to outcome from this issue, any thing i am missing ?

Comment: Are you using Source Control? Have you tried going back and build again? Or did you update VS? Anything else that could've changed?

Comment: @PaulKertscher yes i have updated my visual studio for mac recently

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#dont-link